# $(selector).each() returns an array under IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8

This code, under IE8, returns arrays for each loop:

```
$("input[type='checkbox'][name='selectedEvents']:checked:not(.hidden)").each(function() {
    //Loop
}
```

If I do `$(this).val();` IE8's console shows `Member not found`. But if I do this under Chrome, it works.
If I do `alert($(this));`, popup shows [Object object]. I tested this object's length: it is 1.

Here is a good example of what I am trying to do: http://jsfiddle.net/6TGVP/1/

Is there a bug or am I doing a mistake?

Comment: You'd have better to explain what are you trying to do here?! Could you provide btw a jsFiddle

Comment: What is the version of jQuery ? Keep in mind that jQuery 2 DOES NOT support IE6, 7 and 8.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `:hidden` in your selector? Or have you applied a class?

Comment: @Magus I am using jQuery 1.10

Comment: Your jsFiddle works as expected in IE8, check it here: http://jsfiddle.net/aQ9MN/show